# Safari 15 Big Sur not able to add gradient to Icon

Tags: html, css, icons, gradient

If I try to add a gradient to a bootstrap icon in safari it doesn't show the gradient, but every browser(Firefox, Chrome, Edge) does.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-5 mb-md-0">
        <!-- Feature item-->
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="bi-cart-check icon-feature text-gradient d-block mb-3"> 
            </i>
            <h3 class="font-alt">Leperchaun</h3>
            <p class="text-muted mb-0">Leperchauns like to hide in your closet!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Feature item-->
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="bi-patch-check icon-feature text-gradient d-block mb-3"></i>
            <h3 class="font-alt">Demon</h3>
            <p class="text-muted mb-0">Everything Apple, they say they are different but are evil!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.text-gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2937f0, #9f1ae2);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #00000000;
}
```

The Icons are there if I change the text-fill color to say red. It will then show the icon with a solid red, but it doesn't show the gradient at all.

Also, if I had text in between the `<i>` tags, it will load the text with a gradient. But the icon will not have the gradient.

Any Ideas?

Comment: have you tried with the linear-gradient (no -webkit- prefix)?

Comment: Spent hours trying a bunch of different stuff last night, pretty sure I tried that, but let me double check. Hopefully get lucky.

Comment: @AHaworth, negative, that didn't work

Comment: @Justin, Could you please make sure you have included the right code for your sample. I tried to copy your code and add Bootstrap CDN files but couldn't see any icons.

Comment: @Azu weird, I just double-checked it on my end and the code works for me. I"m using: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">